# Looking for BibTeX style that doesn't include article's title

Tags: bibtex

Please give a name of `.bst` file witch generates article reference entry like this:

> [1] A. Author, Journal_name, 2(3), 45(2014)

2 -- volume number
3 -- issue number
45 -- first page of article
2014 -- year

I guess this reference entry format should be popular. But I have failed to find the `.bst` file.

Comment: `do't`--> doesn't? It is unclear from the title

Comment: There's a possibly huge number of style files that might meet your needs. Can you tell us which style file you've been working with so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many journals provide styles that might be according to your needs. For example you could check out the A&A style:

http://www.aanda.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=160&Itemid=173

[LaTeX files can be found here: ftp://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/readme.html ]